# Simple SVG Path not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

i have tried some basic examples like text, rect, circle, everything went fine. i just moved to `Path` element. I struggle to view the path in the browser. This is the code snippet i used

```
<svg width="500" height="200">
    <path d="M 20 35 L 120 100 Z"> </path>
</svg>
```

but seems its not working. i have tested chrome and firefox. can someone figure it out in correct way. Thanks in advance. 
also i just created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zgck5r4r/)

Comment: The initial value of stroke is [none](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html), which means [no paint is applied](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) unless you specify a color in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add `stroke` and `stroke-width` attributes for showing the path:

```html
    <svg width="500" height="200">
        <path stroke="#f00" stroke-width="3" d="M 20 35 L 120 100 Z"> </path>
    </svg>
```

Or add the third point like this:

```html
    <svg width="500" height="200">
        <text y="20">SVG Test</text>
        <path d="M 20 35 L 120 100 L 0 100 Z"> </path>
    </svg>
```